# How to execute a sql query inside a setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I need to execute a sql query once I clicked on a button. I tried it using `post()` in button click but it refreshes the page and my `slideToggle()` is not working,so I don't get what I expected.I just only need to change a column status in database using this. Below code shows an alert from the `setTimeOut function` and also my `slideToggle()` is working but, it is not executing my query. Please help me to change this function.

```
  <input id="button_close" type="submit" name="submit_NewCat" value="THANK YOU !" onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);$('#birthdaycard1').slideToggle(2000);" />

  <script>
      function myFunction() {
          alert('Hello');

          executeSql("update customer_info set card_status = 'Done' where username = '$user' ;");
      }

      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#birthdaycard1").slideToggle(3000);
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: How do you verify this query isn't executed? Do you know *WebSQL* is deprecated?

Comment: It didn't change the column status of my database

Comment: Tell us what DBMS you use. Also tell us how your javascript application connects to it

Comment: I use phpmyadmin..I'm sorry I don't know wht you meant about connecting javascript but I display some data within the same page using the database

Comment: What is tx in your function argument? You didn't pass the value to tx when you call it....

Comment: I used tx to call my executeSql() inside script

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: WHAT IS tx?

Comment: I'm not passing anything to tx..Can have the function without it as well

Comment: Then it is the problem..if you dont pass anything to tx, why brother use tx.executeSql....? since it is undefined in the scope of that function...

Comment: I really don't know about this.. I was ony try to achive what I wanted to

Comment: Would you mind uploading the working js so that I could figure out what tx is since I suppose you use it in other functions?

Comment: Sure..I just updated my question by including all the scripts I use inside my page.. I don't use anything else except these... I don't use the same js in my other sunctions, it's just for this one

Comment: I assume you have included all your information in that code. There are few thing you need to be aware of.
1. you are missing openDatabase step to connect to your db
2. I believe tx means transaction. You have to use transaction to execute your query  e.g. database.transaction()

Simple Tutorial : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

Comment: You are using PHPMYADMIN right? If yes then let me tell you the code you have written is for websql not for MYSQL you cannot update server side database using above code. If you want to change server side DB make ajax call.

Comment: thank you for the guidence  SerMintt  and Vinie.. I will try this out..